How do I create a Solana 1v1 betting system for a game?
I have a Photon Fusion server-authoritative 1v1 game. The idea is to allow each player to put-up a certain amount of SOL before the match starts. The winner of the match receives the bet pool.
Are there any available templates for such a usecase?
